# Red: any alternative to using do for adding dynamic keys to a block

Tags: rebol, red

Is there an alternative syntax for :

```
a: [
b: [
    1 2
]
]

append (do "a/b") 3   

== [
    b: [
        1 2
    ]
]
```

I don't feel this as very elegant using do (it ressembles too much eval in javascript).

I tried to-path without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re comment that you want a/b in a variable:

```
a: [b: [1 2 3]]
var: a/b
append var 4
probe a
== [b: [1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: Why this doesn't work though:
  a: [b: [1 2 3]]
  var: to-path "a/b"
  append var 4
  probe a

Comment: @user310291: because then you append to the path, not to what the path is supposed to access.

Comment: @PeterLewerin yes I can see ;) but how to append to the block instead if I need to use string type for "a/b" ?

Comment: @user310291: Red isn't Javascript. In a language with meta-circular evaluation, a construct like `do` / `eval` isn't just appropriate, it is indispensible. It's better to go with the language than to try to go against it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use path notation to "address" the inner block directly:

```
>> a: [ b: [ 1 2 ] ]
== [b: [1 2]]
>> append a/b 3
== [1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial assignment

`a: [b: [1 2]]
== [b: [1 2]]`

you want to append 3 to the inner block. You can get the inner block by

`do "a/b"
== [1 2]`

but you can also get it by

`probe a/b
== [1 2]`

which lets you append like this instead:

`append a/b 3
== [1 2 3]
probe a
== [b: [1 2 3]]`

In an Algol-style language, this would be something like `a.b = append(a.b, 3)`: the `a/b` is an assignable dereference to the inner block.

**ETA:**

If you want to bottle up the dereference, the alternative to your `do "a/b"` could be to create a function:

`ab: function [][a/b]
== func [][a/b]
append ab 7
== [1 2 7]`

(Alternatively, `ab: does [a/b]`.)

Comment: this is not dynamic for me: what I meant is that a/b should a string or be stored in a variable

Comment: @user310291: It's a good idea to state that intent in the question. In any case, if you want to do that, then you need to evaluate it, either with `do` or with a function (see edit).

Answer (score 1):

> Why this doesn't work though: a: [b: [1 2 3]] var: to-path "a/b" append var 4

This does (note the GET)

```
a: [b: [1 2 3]]
var: load "a/b"
append get var 4
probe a
== [b: [1 2 3 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As path notation is just a shortcut to **select** you can circumvent the path by using  select

in Red

```
>> a: [ b: [ 1 2 ] ]
== [b: [1 2]]
>> append select a 'b 3
== [1 2 3]
>> a
== [b: [1 2 3]]
```

in Rebol you have to do

```
>> append select a to-set-word 'b 3
== [1 2 3]
```

By the way, why do you not use `a: [ b [ 1 2 ] ]` or do you want to assign the inner block to the global variable `b` ? Then a simple **do a** would do it and you can use

```
>> do a
== [1 2]
>> append b 3
== [1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a: [b: [ 1 2 3]] 
append a/b 4

probe a
== [b: [1 2 3 4]]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow. While this code may solve the problem the OP had, it is advisable to include some context or an explanation of how it addresses the problem, why this method is better etc. Please edit the answer and include more information.